# Disconnect main power if sub-module failed

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, circuit-protection, subcircuit, fail-safe

I am working on a power supply for a stepper motor driver which requires 48 V and 12 V to operate. The 12 V rail must present all the time if it was cut off for any reason then the 48V should also be disconnected! I am feeding the 48 V to a DC-DC Buck to get the 12 V rail.

[image]

I do not want to use a mechanical relay so I came up with this circuit to disconnect the 48 V in case the 12 V output of the buck converter was shutdown for any reason.

[image]

I have noticed that it has a very slow response time, it may take up to 600 ms starting from disconnecting the 12 V till the 48 V disconnects(!) which is not accepted; I want it to be in the range of few milliseconds! I tested this circuit with 48 V and 12 V lab power supply with load up to 100 W.

So how to improve this circuit to have a faster response or maybe if it is not suitable at all, may be I should replace it with something else!

**EDIT**

The 48 V circuitry with the buck converter are on a sperate rail and the p-mos switch circuit will be the main entry point supply for the stepper motor driver circuit and will be fed directly from the 48 V (after reverse polarity protection and the 12 V source), so in normal conditions, the 48 V rail with the buck converter will work and supply the p-mos switch circuit with the required voltage which will supply the driver circuit but if the buck converter stopped working for any reason, the p-mos switch circuit will not work and the the driver circuit will not be supplied with the 12 V and the 48 V.
The power supply circuit is still under development and is not meant to be a final product yet! so I added several components just for extra protection in the development phase!

**EDIT**

I found that my bench power supply is the cause for the long time response, it would take up to 500 ms to go below 0.7 V .

Now I would like to know if the the pmos switch circuit has any hidden issues with-in the current configuration or there is any other better solution .

Comment: You realize that the left-most TVS, the left-most LED and the PMOSFET have an on-going competition over who will go off first in case of reverse polarity? My bet is on the TVS since it has nearly zero resistance. Should be a nice pyrotechnic effect at 3A, the fuse will not save the day. And the P MOS is just a BoM filler brick.

Comment: How can your circuit ever begin if it requires 12 volts to be present to activate the 48 volts and, 12 volts needs the 48 volts to be present?

Comment: @Lundin No competition -- that's a unidirectional type, so the reverse is about a volt. Conveniently, the PMOS can be skipped; the fuse won't be happy about it though!

Comment: At what load current was the 600ms "disconnect" measured?  On both the buck reg and the 12V supply.

Comment: @Lundin some components are added for extra protect during the development phase

Comment: @Andyaka, I have made edit to the post and added extra explanation about what you have mentioned

Comment: I tested the circuit with 48V @2.3A

Comment: The 12V supply was 100 mA

Comment: You need a 10 V zener diode in series with R38 if you don't want to wait until C22 is down to 0.7 V.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hmm, it really ought to be drawn as one (or as a zener to begin with). And I don't see how the PMOS can be skipped for polarity protection, otherwise the rest of the PCB will get energized backwards and the path of least resistance will take the blow.

Comment: The first TVS is to prevent voltages over ~ 48 V and the pmos for the reverse polarity, removing the pmos will definitely allow reverse polarity current to go flow.